# C passing a struct by reference

Tags: c

```
struct Args{
    char *name;
    int counter;
};

void *Producer(void* args){
    struct Args *data = (struct Args*) args;
    //change counter value here which should be changed in main too
}

int main(){
    ...
    ...

    int counter = 0; //will be updated in Producer function
    struct Args args;
    args.counter = counter;
    args.name = "";
    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, Producer, &args);
    return 0;
}
```

I can only pass struct to a thread function and I have a counter that I would like to be updated by each thread...I can make it global but have to pass it as a struct. How do I do achieve this?

Comment: You create a thread and immediately terminate the main thread. This is pointless and potentially segfault by invalide `args` address.

Comment: The scope of the struct you are passing can be local, as long as its lifetime is longer than the thread's lifetime. If it's local to `main`, then main will see the changes done on a separate thread, although you should use `volatile int counter`.

Comment: What you mean by you can make it as global but have to pass it as struct?  Any way you can use global data inside thread

Comment: Since the thread routine expects a pointer so you have correctly passed the address of struct. Inside thread `Producer` you can update the counter as `data->counter += 1;`.  Note*: [1] you need to synchronize the access to shared struct by multiple threads [2] you need to wait inside `main` for threads to get completed.

Comment: 1. Why don't you pass the address of the structure? 2. Why are you not using `pthread_join`?

Comment: Off-topic: The cast `(struct Args*)` is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to reference a **local** variable from different threads, you can use a code like this:

```
struct Args{
    char *name;
    int *counter_ptr;
};

void *Producer(void* args){
    struct Args *data = (struct Args*) args;
    //change counter value here which should be changed in main too
    *(data->counter_ptr)++;
}

int main(){
    ...
    ...

    int counter = 0; //will be updated in Producer function
    struct Args args;
    args.counter_ptr = &counter;
    args.name = "";
    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, Producer, &args);
    // You need to join thread here to prevent program termination.
    return 0;
}
```

But generally speaking, I don't think there is any reason for this here.

Comment: I don't see the point in doing this, vs. simply updating an `int` field.

Comment: @Groo yea,there is no point in doing it, but I guess this is what he want to do.